# Better understanding scope

Tags: c#, scope, instantiation

I'm still very new to C#, but I thought I understood the concept of scope.  I'm having a problem with a program and I would really appreciate some help.

The problem with the following code is that Line 35 fails with

> "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property".

You can see that object Mail is instantiated as part of the Program class and it seems like it should be globally accessible.  But when I try to use Mail.Add in the InitMail() method, it doesn't recognize the Mail object.

If I move the instantiation and InitMail code into Main(), it works just fine (although I also have to remove public modifier on the instantiation).  What am I not understanding here?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace TestApp1103
{
    class Program
    {
        // Define an enum type named "Division" specifying all possible values:
        public enum Division {PFR, PSE, PVF, PVM, PVS}

        //Define a generic class named "MailList" and specify accessor methods:
        public class MailList
        {
            public Division Div { get; set;}
            public string[] SuccAddr { get; set; }
            public string[] FailAddr { get; set; }
        }

        // Instantiate a MailList object named "Mail":
        public List<MailList> Mail = new List<MailList>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Populate the object "Mail":
            InitMail();
        }

        static void InitMail()
        {
            Mail.Add( new MailList()
            {
            Div = Division.PFR,
            SuccAddr = new string[2] { "addr1@contoso.com", "addr2@contoso.com" },
            FailAddr = new string[2] { "addr3@contoso.com", "addr4@contoso.com" }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know a different programing language?

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with scope; `Mail` is in scope. If it were not in scope then the error would be "I can't find anything called Mail in scope".

Comment: Offtopic, but maybe useful: consider renaming mail and maillist. Right now, you have a list of objectlists and you call it object, whereas i believe most people would be more comfortable with a list of objects being called an objectlist :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Mail` is an *instance* field - not a static one.

That means it belongs to instances of the class it is declared on - which there are none.

There are a couple of ways to go about fixing the issue:

1. Make the field static.
2. Instantiate `Program` and call `InitMail` on the variable.

Comment: Oded: I used your fist suggestion to make the field static.  I changed the instantiation line to include the static modifier like so: `public static List<MailList> Mail = new List<MailList>();` and that appears to work.  Thanks VERY MUCH for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
static void InitMail() {
        Mail.Add( new MailList() {
        // properties
        });
    }
```

This will try to add a new `MailList` object to `Mail`. 
However when we look at `Mail`, we see this declaration:

`public List<MailList> Mail = new List<MailList>();`

Notice the absence of `static` which is present in `InitMail()`.
This means that when the method `InitMail()` would be executed statically (`Program.InitMail()`), it would try to access the non-static variable `Mail`.

Thus the compiler complains.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the instance variable `Mail` from a static method.

This can not work as you need an object instance of your class `Program` to access the instance variable